# How to use SEPA in braintree without using paypal account?

Tags: paypal, braintree

My requirement is to use SEPA without entering PayPal details or creating an account.

Answer (score -1):

<sub>Full disclosure: I work at Braintree. If you have any further questions, feel free to contact [support](https://help.braintreepayments.com/).</sub>

In order to process local payment methods, you need to have a valid PayPal business account. There is not a way to currently accept local payment methods or SEPA without a PayPal business account.